# Split large resolution into 2 desktops

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, resolution, intel

I am trying to find a solution to a limitation we have with a split DisplayPort to 2 monitors.  It creates a single display across each monitor.

As far as hardware goes our hands are tied since we cannot get DisplayPort to properly recognize them as separate displays, and USB to DisplayPort is also not an option.

So now we are trying to virtualize the displays.  One solution I thought might work is to get multiple workspaces to appear at once, and give each half of the resolution.  I do not know how to do this however, so I am hoping someone here does, or hoping someone knows how to do this properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***What you're trying to do is impossible.***

A "DisplayPort Splitter" doesn't add any functionality to the existing "DisplayPort": it just does what it's designed to do: transmit electrical signals from one wire to two wires.  (note: electr**ic**, not electr**onic**) So you cannot get multiple workspaces to display on one monitor and have half on one and the other half on the other.

You could create a large virtual screen (contrarily to a workspace) with a resolution twice as wide as your current display and pan around this virtual screen, *but the second monitor would still be displaying exactly what the first monitor is displaying*: that is half a screen and an exact copy at that.

Sorry to be the harbinger of bad news.

Comment: Don't thank me!  ;-) Just click the little grey check-mark under the "0" now.  If you do not like my answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, turning it into beautiful green and if you *really* like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, go to http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask

Comment: Its fine :P, I knew it was a long shot.